# Why I do not see my 2nd Generation Package in my Dev Hub Manage package?

Tags: 2gp, second-generation-packaging

Recently I have created a 2nd Gen Package and I have been waiting to see it in my Setup> packaging>manage packages on my Dev Hub org. (Package has already one promoted version)
I currently in the process of publishing it in the AppExchange and I would like to update the name for example.

Comment: This shows 1GPs and installed packages. 2GPs are visible via the CLI commands instead. You update properties of the managed package through the CLI and your sfdx-project.json file.